# How to prove the longer geodesic joining two points on a 2-sphere is a saddle point of the length function?

Tags: differential-geometry, spheres, geodesic

I am using the following definition of geodesic:

1. Let $S$ be a regular surface. A proper variation of a parametrized curve $\gamma: [a,b] \to S$ is a smooth map
   $$\Gamma:(-\epsilon,\epsilon)\times [a,b] \to S$$
   satisfying $\Gamma(0,s)=\gamma(s), \Gamma(t,a)=\gamma(a), \Gamma(t,b)=\gamma(b).$
2. A parametrized curve $\gamma:I \to S$ is  a geodesic on $S$ if for all proper variations $\Gamma$  of $\gamma$, we have
   $$\frac{d}{dt}\ell(\Gamma(t,s))|_{t=0}=0.$$

By this definition, if we take two separate non-antipodal points on a 2-sphere, there are two geodesics connecting these points, both are parts of the great circle passing through these points. It is easy to see that the shorter geodesic is the minimal point of the length function above. Some people say that the longer geodesic is the saddle point of the length function but I could not see why. It seems to me that the longer geodesic is a local maximal point by looking at smooth deformation (proper variation) nearby it. Am I missing something?

Comment: How can it be a maximum? Just make the path more wiggly.

Comment: Can it be a local maximum? when we take $\epsilon$ small enough and guarantee that the deformation is smooth, then the wiggly path may have a smaller length.

Comment: @MidoAn But it may also have a larger length. Depending on the shape of the deformation. Say a small bump somewhere.

Comment: It seems to me that due to the smoothness of the deformation, at some point ($\epsilon$ small enough), the bump will be small enough so that the length of the curve is less than the length of $\gamma$.

Comment: @Arthur: Oh, I see what you mean! Thanks a lot.